# I want to create trigger to update inserted or updated value in a column based on multiple string filter

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table called `tbl_A` with a column called `DESC`.

The old application inserts and updates values in this `DESC` column like `'H PP'` or `'H CC'` or `'CR BB'`.

I want to replace those inserted values with `'HPP'` or `'HCC'` or `'CRBB'`. Or you could say I want to remove the space between strings.

This is my trigger so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TrgUpd
ON Tbl_A
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Tbl_A
    SET desc = 'HPP'
    FROM Tbl_A A
    INNER JOIN UPDATED u ON a.id = u.id 
    WHERE u.desc = 'H PP'
END
```

Comment: SO is not a free code-writing service, what have you researched and tried so far? Exactly what are you having a problem with?

Comment: @stu I'm Sorry to use such word. I am not a developer. Just started to learn. I written for single condition but not able code for multiple conditions

Comment: There is no `UPDATED` pseudo table in a SQL Server trigger - you only have `Inserted` (for the new values - after an INSERT or an UPDATE), and `Deleted` (for the deleted rows - or the old version in an UPDATE scenario, with the old values, before the update has taken place)

Comment: @marc_s yes true I updated ..Thanks you

Comment: You're on the way to get the elements the answer needs. Anyway, you should refer to what problem you found when executing your trigger.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `UPDATED` pseudo table in a SQL Server trigger. In your case, you'd have to inspect the `Deleted` pseudo table which contains the "old" values - those before the `UPDATE` happened. Also: you can just trim out the spaces - something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TrgUpd
ON Tbl_A
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE A
    SET [Desc] = REPLACE(d.[Desc], ' ', '')
    FROM Tbl_A A
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON a.id = d.id 
END
```

**UPDATE:** if you want to explicitly specify what strings to replace - use this code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_upd_inrt
ON [dbo].[tbl_A]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE A
    SET [Desc] = CASE i.[Desc]
                     WHEN 'HR DD' THEN 'HRDD'
                     WHEN 'H PP' THEN 'HPP'
                     WHEN 'RPT AR' THEN 'RPTARIN'
                     WHEN 'APPP PPLE' THEN 'APPLE'
                     WHEN 'HR DD' THEN 'HRDD'
                 END 
    FROM tbl_A a
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON a.id = i.id 
END
```

Comment: @ArunVishwakarma: well - an `INSERT` trigger doesn't have a `Deleted` pseudo table - only `Inserted` - but yes, basically, the same method will work on this, too

Comment: Its worked well...Thanks

Comment: getting error:
Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_upd, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 0]
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

Comment: @ArunVishwakarma: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.