# I am getting error while updating a column in a table on while trigger configured

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I get this error:

> Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_upd, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

when I use this trigger in my database:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_upd_inrt
ON [dbo].[tbl_A]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE A
    SET [Desc] = CASE i.[Desc]
                     WHEN 'HR DD' THEN 'HRDD'
                     WHEN 'H PP' THEN 'HPP'
                     WHEN 'RPT AR' THEN 'RPTARIN'
                     WHEN 'APPP PPLE' THEN 'APPLE'
                     WHEN 'HR DD' THEN 'HRDD'
                     ELSE Desc
                 END 
    FROM tbl_A a
    INNER JOIN deleted i ON a.id = i.id 
END
```

Comment: So THINK about what your triggers does. You have a statement that updates your table. That will cause your trigger to fire - which updates the same table. Which then causes the same trigger to fire which updates the same table. And so on. There is an option to disable this [trigger recursion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-trigger-recursion-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver150 or you can correct the logic to avoid recursion. BTW what happens when Desc does not contain one of the 5 values? Test thoroughly.

Comment: @SMor ELSE Desc. I don't want to disable the TRIGGER. I update the code

Comment: You did not read the link. Disable **trigger recursion**. But you suffer from a common mistake. You should NEVER update rows that do not need to be updated. And a trigger should check to determine if the action it performs does in fact need to be performed. You will be surprised to learn that the inserted table can contain zero rows when the trigger executes.

Comment: If you are using code from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69242076/2029983) you should really be citing it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't make it really simple to do what you want.  You need to use an `instead of` trigger and update *all* columns:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_upd_inrt ON [dbo].[tbl_A] INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE A
        SET [Desc] = CASE i.[Desc]
                         WHEN 'HR DD' THEN 'HRDD'
                         WHEN 'H PP' THEN 'HPP'
                         WHEN 'RPT AR' THEN 'RPTARIN'
                         WHEN 'APPP PPLE' THEN 'APPLE'
                         WHEN 'HR DD' THEN 'HRDD'
                         ELSE i.[Desc]
                     END,
            COL1 = i.Col1,
            COL2 = i.Col2,
            . . . -- all the rest of the columns that might be updated
        FROM tbl_A a INNER JOIN
             inserted i
             ON a.id = i.id ;

END;
```

Note that this uses the *new* value rather than the *old* value for the replacement.  That makes sense to me.  I assume that you really intend `inserted` rather than `deleted` because of the table alias.

If you do need both values, just include both in the `FROM` clause:

```
    FROM tbl_A a INNER JOIN
         inserted i
         ON a.id = i.id INNER JOIN
         deleted d
         ON d.id = d.id
```